# Git apply three-way error "repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge."

Tags: git

I have a Git diff created with

```
git diff --full-index --ignore-submodules > mypatch.diff
```

And when trying to apply it to another Git repository (same remote branch, more advanced revision) I get the error in the title

```
git apply --3way mypatch.diff
...
error: patch failed: dir/file:189
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: dir/file: patch does not apply
```

This happens for several files.

The documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply state

> When the patch does not apply cleanly, fall back on 3-way merge if the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to, and we have those blobs available locally, possibly leaving the conflict markers in the files in the working tree for the user to resolve.

The interesting thing in my case is that the files (blobs in Git terminology) are in the destination repository (not even renamed), so they must be found by "git apply".

NOTE: The sequence of commands has worked several times in the past.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably need to run `git fetch` (and you may need to tweak your `fetch` refspecs, and/or use `--unshallow`).

#### What's happening

The blob(s) that Git needs are specific versions of the files (pathnames are irrelevant at this point).

For instance, consider this bit of patch:

```
diff --git a/fmt.py b/fmt.py
index 2069319..0c8a68f 100755
--- a/fmt.py
+++ b/fmt.py
@@ -207,7 +207,8 @@ def main():
```

Let's take a look at commit `7124b135...`'s version of `fmt.py`, and then its parent's version:

```
$ git rev-parse 7124b135:fmt.py
0c8a68f9dc05a7399d06693c0b2761fb43ed0b58
$ git rev-parse 7124b135^:fmt.py
2069319dae4bd87cb6e1b7c18d86ebededeb00c8
```

Now look back at that `index ...` line:

```
index 2069319..0c8a68f 100755
```

There are those blob IDs.  Git is comparing blob `2069319...` against blob `0c8a68f...`, which are the versions in the parent of the commit being shown, and the commit itself.

If I were to send this patch to you, and you asked your Git to apply it and it did not apply cleanly, Git's "fall back to 3-way merge" requires that it find or construct three versions of the file: your current one, the one identified by `2069319`, and my version.

Clearly your Git has your current version, so there's no problem there.  Clearly it does not have my version, so it must construct it.  The way it can construct it is to find version `2069319`.

The complaint you are seeing is because your Git cannot find, in your repository, anything identified by the SHA-1 ID on the left of the `..` in the `index <sha1>..<sha1> <mode>` line.

(If your Git *could* find that blob, it would extract it to a temporary file, apply the patch to that temporary file, and hence have my version; and then it would have the three versions it needs to do a 3-way merge.)

#### Where will Git get that blob?

If the patch is against a commit that is currently in a repository that you can `git fetch` from, you should be able to run `git fetch` and obtain that commit, which will obtain all the trees and blobs associated with that commit.

This `git fetch` needs to pick up that commit.  The commits that `git fetch` normally picks up are all the ones in `refs/heads/*` on the remote, as controlled by the `fetch =` line(s) associated with that particular remote, that you don't already have.<sup>1</sup>

It's possible that the commit(s) in the remote that retain this blob there are not under `refs/heads/*` (e.g., if it's only in a stash now, or attached to an outdated tag or a branch that was rebased).  In this case, `git fetch` probably *won't* bring over the necessary blob.  There is a way to get it if you can log in on the remote: just make a branch or tag that points to a commit that leads to the blob in question.  (Finding such a commit can be hard, unless your patch has the commit ID right in it, then it's easy.)  Then direct your Git to fetch that branch or tag from the other Git, and you'll get the necessary blob.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that if you've made a *shallow* clone, Git won't proceed past your existing commits.  Your commits end at some cut-off point, which is what makes your clone shallow.  If the missing blob is on an ordinary branch after all, but is "below" a cutoff, you will need to deepen your repository, either with a deeper `--depth=` argument, or by adding `--unshallow` to your fetch command, so as to deepen it "all the way".

Computing the correct depth is impossible on the shallow-clone side.  (The count is: "How many commits down do I have to dig from a branch tip, to get to the target commit?"  What you have in your repository stops before we get that far, so we don't know how far it is.  We could count how far down *all* of your branches go, and pick a number bigger than that, which would definitely deepen your repository—but we don't know if that's the right number.)

It *is* possible on the *other* repository, but if you have direct access to that repository, you don't have to count, you can just make a branch or tag name pointing to the commit.

What this means in the end that the easiest thing, by far, is to just use `git fetch --unshallow`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, this [helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757246/git-status-and-git-diff-empty-after-failed-git-am).  Having a shallow history from cloning the repo with `--depth 1` also confounds this problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting, another buglet relating to shallow clones. Mercurial was going to add shallow clones but never managed it. Git starts from a slightly easier position, since Git commits are snapshots rather than deltas and file identity is computed dynamically. But that leaves you with these nagging issues, like not being able to find a blob that the graph implies *should* exist.

Answer (score 0):

This will work better with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021): "[`git apply --3way`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/771c758e8a89d4d7aa482e7f98d8878214630301/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L86)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---3way))</sup> has always been to fall back to 3-way merge only when straight application fails".
**Swap the order of falling back so that 3-way is always attempted first** (only when the option is given, of course) and then straight patch application is used as a fallback when it fails.

The issue describe in [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577782/6309) is still there, and a fetch is still needed, but by swapping the order, git am will apply more patches first, before the error.

See [commit 923cd87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/923cd87ac8550a8e277bfeb19198a11b6a8ed854) (06 Apr 2021) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 771c758](https://github.com/git/git/commit/771c758e8a89d4d7aa482e7f98d8878214630301), 15 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/923cd87ac8550a8e277bfeb19198a11b6a8ed854): try threeway first when "`--3way`" is used
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> The `apply_fragments()` method of "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/923cd87ac8550a8e277bfeb19198a11b6a8ed854/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> can silently apply patches incorrectly if a file has repeating contents.
> In these cases a three-way merge is capable of applying it correctly in more situations, and will show a conflict rather than applying it incorrectly.
> However, because the patches apply "successfully" using `apply_fragments()`, git will never fall back to the merge, even if the "--3way" flag is used, and the user has no way to ensure correctness by forcing the three-way merge method.
>
> Change the behavior so that when "--3way" is used, git will always try the three-way merge first and will only fall back to `apply_fragments()` in cases where blobs are not available or some other error (but not in the case of a merge conflict).
>
> Since user-facing results will be different, this has backwards compatibility implications for users depending on the old behavior.
> In addition, the three-way merge will be slower than direct patch application.

`git apply` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/923cd87ac8550a8e277bfeb19198a11b6a8ed854/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L87-L88):

> Attempt 3-way merge if the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed
> to apply to and we have those blobs available locally, possibly leaving the conflict markers in the files in the working tree for the user to resolve

The message changes from:

```
(if error) repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge
(else)     Falling back to three-way merge...
```

To:

```
(if error) repository lacks the necessary blob to perform 3-way merge.
(else)     Performing three-way merge...
```

Even better:

Still with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a7e52bed263c1dbc181ece54b73ee4318e79fca/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> now takes `--3way` and `--cached` at the same time, and work and record results only in the index.

See [commit c0c2a37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0) (07 Apr 2021) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a7e52b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a7e52bed263c1dbc181ece54b73ee4318e79fca), 15 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0): allow simultaneous `--cached` and `--3way` options
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> does not allow `--cached` and `--3way` to be used together, since "`--3way`" writes conflict markers into the working tree.
>
> Allow "`git apply`" to accept `--cached` and `--3way` at the same time.
> When a single file auto-resolves cleanly, the result is placed in the index at stage #0 and the command exits with 0 status.
>
> For a file that has a conflict which cannot be cleanly auto-resolved, the original contents from common ancestor (stage conflict at the content level, and the command exists with non-zero status, because there is no place (like the working tree) to leave a half-resolved merge for the user to resolve.
>
> The user can use [`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> to view the contents of the conflict, or [`git checkout -m -- .`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L243)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--m))</sup> to regenerate the conflict markers in the working directory.
>
> Don't attempt `rerere` in this case since it depends on conflict markers written to file for its database storage and lookup.
> There would be two main changes required to get `rerere` working:
>
> 1. Allow the rerere api to accept in memory object rather than
>    files, which would allow us to pass in the conflict markers
>    contained in the result from ll_merge().
> 2. Rerere can't write to the working directory, so it would have to
>    apply the result to cache stage #0 directly. A flag would be
>    needed to control this.

`git apply` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0c2a37ac2b9338c3a93340cbcbab69690da4df0/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L90-L93):

> This option implies the `--index` option unless the
> `--cached` option is used, and is incompatible with the `--reject` option.
> When used with the `--cached` option, any conflicts are left at higher stages in the cache.

---

And, still with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), when the order of `--3way` fallback was swapped, the order was incorrect between message given when the first method fails and the second method is attempted (which used to be "direct application failed hence we try 3way", now it is the other way around).

See [commit 526705f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/526705fd3d14a38646a12235ee385dcc0ffc7321) (28 Apr 2021) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d99f31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d99f31ddafb064795d1d8f9b9bd930296f7069e), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/526705fd3d14a38646a12235ee385dcc0ffc7321): adjust messages to account for `--3way` changes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/526705fd3d14a38646a12235ee385dcc0ffc7321/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> specifically calls out when it is falling back to 3way merge application.
> Since the order changed to preferring 3way and falling back to direct application, continue that behavior by printing whenever 3way fails and git has to fall back.

Answer (score 0):

You may also just miss the `index 2069319..0c8a68f 100755` line in the patch. Git then prints the same message, but no additional commits would ever help it.

```
(set -ex;rm -rf gitgit;mkdir gitgit;cd gitgit;git init;echo a >x;git add x;git commit -am.;git checkout -b b;echo b >x;git commit -am.;git checkout master;echo c >x;git commit -am.;git diff master^..b|grep -v ^index >b.diff;git apply -3 b.diff || cat b.diff)
error: patch failed: x:1
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: x: patch does not apply
```