# git status and git diff empty after failed git am

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm developing on a different machine than I usually do, and it seems that git is behaving differently than I remember.

When I checkout a new branch `git checkout -b <new branch name>`, and try to apply a patch `git am </path/to/file.patch>`, the patch fails to apply:

```
</path/to/file.patch>
Applying: <commit msg>
error: patch failed: <filename>:<line no>
error: <filename>: patch does not apply
Patch failed at <commit msg>
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

Now I swear on my other machines when a patch fails to apply, `git status` and `git diff` will show the file as modified with `<<< HEAD >>>>` markers showing where I need to fix the three way merge.  Currently `git status` shows I'm in the middle of an `am` operation, but no files changed, as does `git diff`.

Am I mis-remembering or does my other machine maybe have an older version of `git`, or even a different config option set?  Why does git not show a merge conflict?  Do I need to set a mergetool? I don't have access to my other machine at the moment, but I'll try to update this post with more info when I can.

edit:

`git am --3way` seems to be what I want. [0][1] But neither `git am --3way <path/to/patch>` nor `git config --global am.threeWay true` seem to work.

ah, it's failing with a different message now:

```
</path/to/file.patch>
Applying: <commit msg>
fatal: sha1 information is lacking or useless (<filename>).            <-- new
error: could not build fake ancestor                                   <-- new
Patch failed at <commit msg>
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

Similary, `git am --3way </path/to/patch>` fails with:

```
error: patch failed: <file>:<lineno>
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: Makefile: patch does not apply
```

Maybe this patch is irredeemable?  Resorting to `patch -p1 < </path/to/path>` applies the first hunk and fails for the second, so I guess I'll just have to do this by hand.

I should note that I'm working out of a shallow repo cloned with `--depth 1`.

[0] https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html
[1] https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Answer (score 17):

Regarding the following error:

```
fatal: sha1 information is lacking or useless (<filename>).
error: could not build fake ancestor
```

This error can also take place when `git am -3` tries to apply a patch that was generated from another repository. Workaround is to add this repository (e.g. patch-origin) for reference as:

```
git remote add patch-origin <path>
git fetch patch-origin
```

After that `git` should be able to build the *ancestor*.

Comment: Had to port an old branch to a now brand new, history re-written repository, and this trick worked great to make the patch applied, even if the two repository don't have any commit in common!

Answer (score 7):

Aha!  [This SO post led me to an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577782/1027966)

Two things going wrong:

set three way merge as the default behavior of `git am`:

`git config --global am.threeWay true`

this was confounded by the fact that I had done a shallow copy (ie. `--depth 1`).  The SO post I linked to explains that without enough history, the warning `fatal: sha1 information is lacking or useless` is saying "not enough info to construct a three way merge."

It would be helpful it git mentioned in this case if you had done a shallow copy to fetch more history...

Comment: The message itself certainly needs to be beefed-up.  I'll add the `git fetch --unshallow` hint to my other answer, too.